# Updating / Saving items generated by wp_terms_checklist on frontend

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-update-post, terms

I'm displaying a list of custom taxonomies from a custom post type on a frontend page which shows any items that the user has previously selected as checked.

I have got it displaying correctly, but I can't manage to work out how to save any new / changed selections.

This is the code I'm using to display the terms :

```
$args = array(
    'descendants_and_self'  => 0,
    'selected_cats'         => false,
    'popular_cats'          => false,
    'walker'                => null,
    'taxonomy'              => 'genres',
    'checked_ontop'         => false
); 

wp_terms_checklist( $my_postid, $args );
```

Which outputs like this on the page :

```
<li id='genres-28'><label class="selectit"><input value="28" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[genres][]" id="in-genres-28" checked='checked' /> 2 Step</label></li>

<li id='genres-14'><label class="selectit"><input value="14" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[genres][]" id="in-genres-14" checked='checked' /> Afro House</label></li>

<li id='genres-7'><label class="selectit"><input value="7" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[genres][]" id="in-genres-7" checked='checked' /> Bassline</label></li>

etc...
```

I'm setting up the post data like this :

```
$post_to_edit = array(
    'ID'           => $my_postid,
    'post_content' => $_POST['editor'],
    'tax_input'    =>  array( 'genres' => array($_POST['tax_input[genres]']) )
);

$pid = wp_update_post($post_to_edit);
```

Then I'm trying to the update the terms like this :

```
wp_set_post_terms($pid,(array)$_POST['tax_input[genres]'],'genres', true);
```

And I've also tried :

```
wp_set_object_terms($pid,(array)($_POST['tax_input[genres]']),'genres');
```

But neither are working?

I'm guessing that I'm not selecting the right name attribute but I've tried everything I can think of for the past 24hrs and just can't get the terms to save to the database.

Does anybody know how I can save/update the values output from `wp_terms_checklist`?

Comment: Update : I'm definitely not selecting the right name tag as when I try to print the array I get - Array ( [0] => )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST['tax_input[genres]']` should be `$_POST['tax_input']['genres']`

Comment: You sir, are a legend! I have been banging my head against the computer screen for hours upon hours trying everything I could think of. Thank yo so much!